# Sorting unicode character in MySQL from least # of characters to most # of characters?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, unicode

I have a MySQL database with thousands of rows in it. Let's assume each row only has one column and each cell contains a Unicode word (i.e. Chinese word). How do I sort the records so the result set comes back with the word that has the least # of characters first?

For example:
If I have AA, BB, CCC, D, EEEE, then I want the result set to be sorted as such: D, AA, BB, CCC, EEEE

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `char_length(your_column)` as unicode character will take more than one byte.

```
select * from table 
order by char_length(col), col;
```

Answer (score 0):

First order by the length of the column, and then by the column it self :

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY length(YourCol),
         YourCol
```

Comment: `CHAR_LENGTH()` for multibyte.